# Mixing Guid and Ints in a single database

Tags: database-design, fluent-nhibernate

### Question

> Is there anything inherently wrong or dangerous with mixing the identity types for the sake of ensuring I do not run out of keys in the near future, or should all types in my database adhere to the same identity strategy?

### Details

A database I am building will require a very large number of tables, and some of them (specifically junction tables) will require an **obese** amount of entries due to the fact that certain elements are aggregate roots that are used in many places with many-to-many relationships.

While the functionality aspect is working fine, I am concerned about the limitations of an *identity* column for certain things. Doing the math, it is not hard to forsee reaching the limits of a 32-bit identity within 2 and a half years of running. My initial thought for this was to use a *Guid* for those specific tables instead of a 32-bit integer, however I have trepidations about mixing the two together. I've heard some pretty bad things about that practice.

I am using `nHibernate`/`Fluent nHibernate` to design my mapping to my database. But for example, I have the following structure...

```
class Member : IIdentity<int>
{
 public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

class Page : IIdentity<Guid>
{
 public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
 // multiple other properties
}
```

There are no less than 8 objects that have an `IList<Page>`, and a `Page` can be re-used between multiple objects (hence, it is a many-to-many relationship). So it is defined in my mapping using `HasManyToMany`. This same principle extends to several other objects.

Comment: You said, "Doing the math, it is not hard to forsee reaching the limits of a 32-bit identity within 2 and a half years of running." I think that would require more than 3000 inserts a minute, every minute, for 2½ years. Is that really what you estimate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great thing about GUID's are that they unique regardless of what database the record comes from.  If you are accessing multiple databases or need to identify objects uniquely apart from the schema then you should go with GUIDS.

Otherwise it is best to go with 32 bit integers.  Your application sounds resource intensive and you need to consider that integers perform better than GUIDS.

Comment: I would really like to, but the sheer number of some of the things that will be inserted may not be sufficient. For example, almost every single element in the database can have an `IList<Page>`, and an `IList<Tag>`. Every element will have a minimum of around 5 of each, and a typical amount of 50 each. Assume 300 elements just at initial launch of the product, and growing by 50 per week. You can start to see my problem.

Comment: So assuming 50 elements with ~ 50 pages each per week you are looking at almost 7 million records in a couple years time.  To be honest, I think you are worried about the wrong things here.  You can use a 64 bit integer for identity.  Even indexed, a 7 million record GUID identity table will perform poorly and even worse when joining it to other tables.

Comment: Another thing you intend on using an ORM mapper in your application, lets face it, they aren't known for formulating efficient performance minded queries.  Does it make sense at all in your application to archive old data, possibly move old data to an archive table or even warehouse it?

Comment: Eh? 300 elements growing at 50 per week gives you about 26,000 elements in 10 years. Multiply that by 50, and you get about 1.3 million (again, in 10 years). That's not even one tenth of one percent of the range of a 32-bit integer. (7 million is less than 2 tenths of one percent.) Did I do the arithmetic wrong?

Comment: @Catcall, I thought he was saying that 50 elements each element with 50 pages. Still, after 10 years under my math thats about 70 million records.  Assuming an unsigned 32 bit integer that is STILL slightly less than 2% of numbers used.  Like I said earler, the OP need not worry about available ids and worry more about large tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bigint identity instead of int identity.  That might give you the breathing room you need without using as much space in your keys.  Something else to consider is the insert rate and whether you're going to get hotspots in your indexes.  Guids will be closer to random whereas ints (or bigints) are going to be sequential.